# How to make scatter plot in spherical coordinates theta, phi, r (w/ or w/o plotly)?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, plotly, polar-coordinates

my question refers mostly to plotly, but plotting alternatives with other packages are welcome!

I have successfully made a light cone plot (kind of a wedge plot) in polar coordinates with this code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter_polar(df_rdwz, r='z', theta='ra',
                       range_theta=[-6,6], range_r=[0.8,3.2], start_angle=0, direction="counterclockwise")
fig.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

But I have as data also a phi angle for the depth. I would like to use it to make this plot 3d. Is there something like `px.scatter_spherical` or `px.scatter_3d_spherical` that would allow me this? Alternatively, I know I can use `go.Scatter3d` with cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) - can I plot the dots in cartesian coordinates and afterwards just make the AXIS of `go.Scatter3d` to be drawn spherically (theta, phi, r)?
Any other suggestions of how to make this plot in 3d with spherical axis labels are welcome! tnx

Comment: https://community.plotly.com/t/surfaces-in-cylindrical-3d-polar-coordinates/17912 https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-parametric-plots/ looks like it would do what you are asking

Comment: @RobRaymond Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I don't see how this solves my problem, because I need to do a scatter plot, not a surface plot, and I need the axis to be displayed in theta,phi,r and not in x,y,z. But maybe I am missing something, can you elaborate how these links would help me? tnx

Comment: to be fair I'm not great on the math, but same concepts apply to calculate x,y & z. what I don't know is anything about your data, can you use **meshgrid** type calcs or does your data already contain all the necessary geometry?

Comment: @RobRaymond I actually even have the x,y,z provided, I don't need to calculate them. My problem is that I need to make the plot so that the axis themselves, the ones that are being displayed, are not x,y,z, but theta, phi, r. Does it make sense what I say?

Comment: it does,  I'm not aware of anyway to do that.  However my knowledge of matplotlib and bokeh is quite limited.  was looking at it from plotly perspective